# Is it possible to align gradients between elements?

Tags: css, gradient

I'm trying to add a gradient to past days in a calendar, but the gradient lines not aligning look a bit meh.

```css
div.month {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  background-color: var(--color-border);

}

div.day {
  background-color: var(--color-fill);
}

div.day + .past {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    var(--color-fill),
    var(--color-fill) 1.5rem,
    var(--color-gradient-calendar-past) 1.5rem,
    var(--color-gradient-calendar-past) 3rem
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="month noselect">
        <div class="day void"><div class="day-number"></div></div>
        <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">1</div></div>
        <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">2</div></div>
        <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">3</div></div>
        <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">4</div></div>
        ...
        <div class="day today"><div class="day-number">17</div></div>
```

Without making the days square (`aspect-ratio: 1/1`), is it possible to align these gradients?

[image]

I was thinking maybe I can make the whole component's background that gradient, but then I run into the same problem if I want to use the same gradient coloured differently on other days.

[image]

Comment: Please add the code for whats on the picture

Comment: Your snippet doesn't reproduce your screenshots. If it did, I would experiment with setting the background on the entire component and using [`background-blend-mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35177384/2518285) to make a red one for today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

Use the gradient as the background for `div.month` and make it red. For the normal `div.day` you add a white background and for the `.past` you make the background transparent and add a `backdrop-filter`.

```css
div.month {
    height: 23vW;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff, #fff 1.5rem, #fdc5d0 1.5rem, #fdc5d0 3rem );
}

div.day {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}

div.day + .past {
    background-color: #0000;
    backdrop-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(1.13);
}

div.day + .blocked {
    background-color: #0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="month noselect">
    <div class="day void"><div class="day-number"></div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">1</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">2</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">3</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">4</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">5</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">6</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">7</div></div>
    <div class="day blocked"><div class="day-number">8</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">10</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">11</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">12</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">13</div></div>
    <div class="day past"><div class="day-number">14</div></div>
</div>
```

By using `grayscale(1)` the background is not red anymore and then I push the brightness a little bit.

I assumed you want to use red for blocked dates. If you want to use more colors than red and grey (for example green for holidays) you can use `hue-rotate`:

```css
div.day + .holiday {
    backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(123deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may get you there, but without the actual code, it's hard to tell.

1. This sets the background of the whole container to the `background-gradient`.
2. It sets a the same background gradient to a pseudo `::after` to a `day` element with the class `today` (this is where you might need to modify for your application).
3. We don't have a position set on the `day` element so using `position: absolute` will position the `pseudo` element against the `month` element, which I set a `position: relative` on.
4. Then you can use `clip-path: content-box;` to restrict the `pseudo` view to only the `.today` class element.

```css
:root {
  --color-border: lightgray;
  --color-fill: white;
  --color-gradient-calendar-past: lightgray;
  --color-gradient-calendar-now: pink;
}

div.month {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, var(--color-fill), var(--color-fill) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-past) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-past) 3rem);
}

div.void {
  background: white;
}

div.day {
  height: 200px;
}

div.today::after {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, var(--color-fill), var(--color-fill) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-now) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-now) 3rem);
}

div.today {
  clip-path: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="month noselect">
  <div class="day void">
    <div class="day-number"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day today">
    <div class="day-number">17</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day today">
    <div class="day-number">17</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Using `inset(0)`

```css
:root {
  --color-border: lightgray;
  --color-fill: white;
  --color-gradient-calendar-past: lightgray;
  --color-gradient-calendar-now: pink;
}

div.month {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, var(--color-fill), var(--color-fill) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-past) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-past) 3rem);
}

div.void {
  background: white;
}

div.day {
  height: 200px;
}

div.today::after {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, var(--color-fill), var(--color-fill) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-now) 1.5rem, var(--color-gradient-calendar-now) 3rem);
}

div.today {
  clip-path: inset(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="month noselect">
  <div class="day void">
    <div class="day-number"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day today">
    <div class="day-number">17</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day past">
    <div class="day-number">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day today">
    <div class="day-number">17</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: clip-path: content-box is not valid in all the browser, you can use clip-path: inset(0)

Comment: @TemaniAfif where do you see that? I didn't see anything on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) or on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=clip-path) about `content-box` not being respected in all browsers. *edit* added `inset(0)` as an alternative

Comment: try it. On chrome it doesn't work

Comment: Sure enough! I can't find a "bug" ticket or issue about this. I see posts about clip-path and chrome, and essentially using the z-index stacking-order trick of applying a generic transform or opacity to adjust the stacking context - but nothing about `content-box`. The other answer is better anyway! ahah